# Как изменить авторизацию и аутентификацию в Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, аутентификация

Аутентификация из коробке происходит по email, а нужно, чтобы по логину. И нужно сделать авторизацию без пароля, то есть после ввода логина должна происходить авторизация. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно написать свою простую авторизацию или переопределить методы авторизации из коробки.
attemptLogin(), credentials(), validateLogin()

Comment: В документации написано, что можно таким образом эти методы 
переопределить в классе AuthController. НО у меня версия 5.5 У меня нет класса AuthController

Comment: LoginController находится в App\Http\Controllers\Auth